# Convert String object to datetime in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a object column as 27/11 as day and month. When I convert it into datetime I am getting 1900-11-27. But I need only 27-11 as a datetime column. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Nope I want that as a date time column but not as object column

Comment: It was clear in the answer that day and month without year is not how `period` works. Either you create dummy year or separate the two into `day` and `month` columns.

Comment: I want only datetime

Comment: Hey @Henry Yik can you contact me I had some doubt regarding to R shiny

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {'date': ['27/11', '14/03', '19/06']}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%M').dt.strftime('%M/%d')
```

Output:

```
    date
0  11/27
1  03/14
2  06/19
```

Or just change the strftime format to get what you want: `dt.strftime('%d-%M')`

```
    date
0  27-11
1  14-03
2  19-06
```

Comment: I want it as a datetime column